# How to center this image

Tags: c#

I have an image that looks like this.  I have the pointy image which looks good and then I have to draw the green image on top of the pointy image.  The idea is to draw the green image in the center of the pointy image.  I am having some problems with that.

```
     var shipImageOffset = new PointF(0, 0);
     using (var bmp = new Bitmap(_shipImage))
     using (var image = ImageUtilities.RotateImage(
        bmp,
        (float)ShipHeading,
        new PointF(this.Width / 2, this.Height / 2),
        shipImageOffset,
        this.Width,
        this.Height))
     {

        e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, new PointF(0,0));

     }


     //paint the green pointer image
     if (_windImageRepo.TryGetValue(needleSpeed, out var windImage))
     {
        //need to figure out the origin point - the origin point is the center of the long rectangle
        //at the bottom
        var center = new PointF(windImage.HorizontalResolution, windImage.VerticalResolution);
        using (var bmp = new Bitmap(windImage))
        {

           for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
           {
              for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
              {
                 var color = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);
                 if (color != Color.FromArgb(0))
                 {
                    bmp.SetPixel(x, y, System.Drawing.Color.LimeGreen);
                 }
              }
           }

           var windImageOffset = new PointF(0,0);
           using (var image = ImageUtilities.RotateImage(
               bmp,
               (float)WindHeading,
               new PointF(this.Width / 2, this.Height / 2),
               windImageOffset,
               this.Width,
               this.Height))
           {

              //This is your image from the pictureBox1
              Bitmap img = new Bitmap(_shipImage);

              // I am targeting the middle of the image, Your case would be the binarized image
              Point index = new Point(img.Size.Width / 2, img.Size.Height / 2);

                              e.Graphics.DrawImage(image,Center(_shipImage));

           }


        }

     }

        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
```

The objective is to get the green pointer in the middle of other image.   Not having luck on that.

[image]

Comment: `this.Width` and `this.Height` should probably be `this.ClientSize.Width` and `this.ClientSize.Height` so that the container borders don't skew the dimensions.

Comment: **Hint:** To center the image horizontally: `x = (drawingCanvas.Width - TheImage.Width) / 2;`. and vertically: `y = (drawingCanvas.Height - TheImage.Height) / 2;`. Also, consider Lars's comment.

Comment: Aslo make sure both images have the same dpi! (It seems to be pretty much centered imo)